# Can someone tell me what is wrong with this statement?

Tags: c++

How is this statement

```
int* p = new int[10];
p[10] = 5;
delete[] p;
```

different with this statement ?

```
int* p = new int[10];
*p = 5;
delete[] p;
```

I wanna what is wrong with the first code. I'm kinda new to C++, so any explanation is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What makes you think that there's something wrong with the statement? (you're correct there is something wrong, but knowing why you think so without understanding the problem will help us know what to explain to you)

Comment: In an array of size `[10]` the valid indices are `[0]` to `[9]`, so `[10]` is out of bounds

Comment: @rzq For future reference, this type of question gets downvoted and closed very quickly so you might want to read [ask] before you ask another question.

Comment: It's only really worth answering due to the equivalence of `p[0]` and `*p`. (Well, I thought so anyway.)

Comment: If it's not obvious how they're different, you need to go back to basics and spend more time reading a good C++ book or tutorial. Being new is fine, but not doing your own minimum of research before asking on SO makes for poor, off-topic questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behaviour of `p[10]` is *undefined* as the array has only 10 elements and the first element is at position 0. You can access `p[0]` (which is the same as `*p`) to `p[9]` inclusive.

In other words, arrays in C++ are *zero-based*. Cf. Fortran, for example, where they are *one-based*.